# Can't boot 5.13 Kernel - kernel panic

Tags: kernel, 21.10

## Issue description

System won't boot on 5.13 Kernel, Currently "works" on 5.11 with no eGPU. System won't boot on any currently installed kernel with eGPU connected.

On 5.13 Kernel, booting doesn't even reach the encryption password step, and just produces a kernel panic with the below error. On 5.11 Kernel, with the eGPU connected, it always gets past the encryption password step, but doesn't always boot into gnome. Sometimes you only get a flashing underscore (once I was able to ctl,alt-f3 into tty3), sometimes only the monitor connected to the eGPU shows gnome, and internal shows Lenovo logo.

In addition, when no eGPU is connected and in 5.11 kernel, it appears still not to have complete functionality. E.g. internal display brightness keys don't work; HDMI port doesn't work.

Apologies if the issue described are two separate issues. The system and all features mentioned have previously worked fine with and without the eGPU connected on 20.04 LTS. (In hindsight I should never have upgraded lol)

## System Information

Lenovo Thinkpad L13 Yoga Gen 2
Ubuntu 21.10
Gnome on Xorg V40.4.0
11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz × 8
Graphics:

- Internal Intel Iris Xe Graphics\
- EGPU - Razer Core X with Geforce RTX 3060 TI

## Kernel panic boot error

*There may be minor errors in the below log, as it was from a screenshot*

```
usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 5.13.0-25-generic xhci-hcd
usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-0:1.0: 4 ports detected
el000e 0000:00:1f.6 0000:00:1f.6 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
el000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width X1) 48:2a:e3:f2:e5:4a
el000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
el000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: MAC: 14, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
el000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: renamed from eth0
nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 510
nvidia 0000:22:00.0: enabling device (0002 -> 0003)
nvidia 0000:22:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
NVRM: loading nvidia UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module 470.86 Tue Oct 26 21:55:45 UTC 2021
nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms 470.86 Tue Oct 26 21:46:51 UTC 2021
[drm] Invidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002200] Loading driver
usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=2817, bcdDeuice=90.24
usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialHumber=0
usb 3-4: Product: USB2.0 Nub
usb 3-4: Manufacturer: VIA labs, Inc.
hub 3-4:1.0: USB hub found
hub 3-4:1.0: 4 ports detected
psmouse serial: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x5f3001)
psmouse seriol: elantech: Symaptics capabilities query result 0x90, 0x18, 0x0d.
psmouse seriol: elantech: Elan sample query result 00, 0d, a7
psmouse seriol: elantech: Elan ic body: 0x11, current fw version: 0x4
Kernel panic - not syncing: stack-protector: Kernel stack is corrupted in: elantech_change_report_id+0x1bf/0x1c4 [psmouse]
CPU: 7 PID: 78 Comm: kworker/7:1 Tainted: P OE 5.13.0-25-generic #26-Ubuntu
Hardware name: LENOVO 20VKCT01WW/20VKCT01WW, BIOS R1FET40W (1.14 ) 12/07/2021
Workgueue: events_long serio_handle_event
Call Trace:
 show_stack+0x52/0x58
 dump_stack+0x7d/0x9c
 panic+0x101/0x2e3
 ? elantech_change_report_id+0x1bf/0x1c4 [psmouse]
 _stack chk_fail+0x14/0x20
 elantech_change_report_id+0x1bf/0x1c4 [psmouse]
 elantech_query_info.cold+0x316/0x594 [psmouse]
 elantech_init+0x34/0x160 [psmouse]
 ? synaptics_send_cmd+0x60/0x60 [psmouse]
 psmouse_extensions+0x4b6/0x520 [psmouse]
 psmouse switch_protocol+0x144/0x190 [psmouse]
 psmouse_connect+0x185/0x3a0 [psmouse]
 serio_driver_probe+0x36/0x50
 really_probe+0x24b/0x4c0
 driver_probe_device+0xf0/0x160
 device_driver_attach+0xab/0xb0
 _driver_attach+0xb2/0x140
 ? device_driver_attach+0xb0/0xb0
 bus_for_each_dev+0x7e/0xc0
 driver_attach+0x1e/0x20
 serio_handle_event+0x10f/0x290
 process_one_work+0x21d/0x3c0
 worker_thread+0x53/0x420
 kthread+0x11c/0x140
 ? process_one_work+0x3c0/0x3c0
 ? set_kthread_struct+0x50/0x50
 ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x30
Kernel Offset: 0x9400000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: stack-protector: Kernel stack is corrupted in: elantech_change_report_id+0x1bf/0x1c4 [psmouse] ]---
```

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer (and add some details). Don't put that in the edited version of the question.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. You have two course of actions. Either write an answer by clicking on the **Answer your own question** button and provide a comprehensive answer that will help others. Then you can mark your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark next to the answer and turn it green. Or you may want to delete the question as the problem was transient and solved itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kernel panic issue was solved by 5.13.0-28 kernel update.
Not booting into gnome issue and other "unusual" functionality issues resolved by purging and reinstalling gdm.